# JQuery, CSS and dialog. Inserting stuff into the buttonpane div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dialog

I have a JQuery dialog. In the buttonpane area, I need to insert clickable text, a button, and a checkbox. I've been struggling to figure out how.

The most recent thing i've been trying is this:

```
$(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").html("sample.html",{})
$("clickableTextDiv").click(function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

This shows the clickable text, but it's not actually clickable. I assume I can then easily add a button/checkbox in the html file. I guess my question is:

Is this how I should be doing it, or is there a better way then including a separate html file?
If this is the way to do it, why isn't the .click working?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Missing a proper selector

```
$("clickableTextDiv").click(function(){
```

//

```
Should be $(".clickableTextDiv")  // If it is a class
```

//

```
Should be $("#clickableTextDiv")  // If it is a id
```